# SparseArray vs HashMap qual a diferença?

Tags: java, android, estrutura-de-dados, hashmap

Estava eu fazendo minha refatorações diária e me deparei com um aviso.

> use new SparseArray(...) to instead for better performance

Ok, mas qual a diferença entre `Map` e `SparseArray`?

O meu código é esse:

```
private Map<Integer,Drawable> mapTooth = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Sugiro [essa leitura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560629/sparsearray-vs-hashmap)

Comment: Obrigado @nullptr, se você pudesse ter falado e mandado o link seria melhor ainda. Afinal creio que alguém novato, que ainda não entende inglês, também pode precisar mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ele é uma otimização do `HashMap`. Java trabalha com tudo calcado em tipos por referência que geram alocação, e portando ocupam mais memória e pressão no *garbage collector*. Ainda é ruim pelo fato que nem todos os objetos são derivados de `Object`, como é em C#, por exemplo, existem os chamados tipos primitivos para dar performance (logo terá formas de criar tipos por valor, o que mostra que a linguagem nasceu torta acreditando na falácia que a orientação a objeto resolveria todos os males). Também não ajuda o fato de *generics* da linguagem ser um remendo que foi feito depois. Então para ter ganhos quando vai usar tipos primitivos em um mapa foi criada uma estrutura específica para lidar com isto de forma mais otimizada.

Ao mesmo tempo que reduz alocação a implementação pode não ser tão boa, eu não garanto que sempre é vantajoso.

A parte ruim é que existem variações dele já que ele não pode usar *generics*. Então [`SparseArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray) na verdade seria o mesmo que `HashMap<int, Object>` se pudesse fazer assim. E se quiser usar um `int` como valor, seria o caso de usar [`SparseIntArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray). Se quiser que a chave seja um `long` seria algo como [`LongSparseArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LongSparseArray). Imagine que fica quase inviável criar todas variações.

O `SparseArray` pode usar *generics*  no tipo do valor, desde que ele seja por referência.

Até onde eu sei não faz parte da biblioteca padrão do Java então o código não fica portável. Uma bela gambiarra para contornar limitação da linguagem. E o aviso parece precipitado, ele não é necessariamente mais rápido. Se você não tem certeza que isto vai melhorar seu código pense bem antes de fazer, teste (tem que saber testar) e veja se compensou.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então "SparseArray" é apenas recomendado para tipos Primitivos e o HashMap quando se usa o Object é isso de uma maneira mais grotesca ? Ou estou totalmente errado ?

Comment: A primeira parte sim, e só para uns três primitivos, a segunda, não, é para todos os tipos herdados de `Object`.